# black artifacts in colliding transparent objects - cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

turning my model transparent shows the overlapping parts as black, is there a way to get rid of it? to clarify, this is not "Z fighting" the faces don't overlap, moving individual parts simply moves the black artifacts. and yes it does show up in the final render with cycles. thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: What are your _Max Bounces_ settings in the _Render Properties_ under _Light Paths_?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer Gordon, increasing the max transparent bounces to 30 resolved the issue.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 Actually I was going to vote to close this question because this has already been answered a dozen times here but I was working and forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

increasing the Max bounces for Transparent light paths fixed the issue

[image]